# How to use bordered prominent style in a custom button style?

Tags: swiftui

I have a custom button style where I'd like to use `.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)`, but I only have access to the label.

This is what my custom button style looks like:

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
       .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
       .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
       .controlSize(.large)
       .tint(.accentColor)
       .foregroundColor(isEnabled ? .black : nil)
  }
}
```

However, `buttonStyle` and `controlSize` has no effect. How can I compose button styles together so I can use native button styles within my custom button style? I'm trying to avoid creating a custom view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ButtonStyle affects only Button, so we need to apply it to Button. As we see `makeBody` returns `some View` so we can put into style *any* view, thus let's put a `Button` inside.

Here is a possible solution. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Here is main part:

```
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button(action: { configuration.trigger() }) {
            configuration.label
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        // ... other code
```

[Complete code and demo](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestProminentInsideStyle.swift)

Comment: This isn’t working for me as the [`ButtonStyleConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyleconfiguration) has no member `trigger`.

Comment: Okay, found it – simply make sure the style struct conforms to the `PrimitiveButtonStyle` protocol! This will convert it to [`PrimitiveButtonStyleConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/primitivebuttonstyleconfiguration) then.